# Excel auto-populate data in master sheet

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

i have a scenario where i have my team members maintaining their data in same workbook but separate worksheets. But i am trying to find a solution or formula where i can consolidate or auto populate data for all in master sheet.

Below is the Tracker used by my team members  (individual tracker).

[image]

Example. If Above template is used by 4 team members in same workbook but in different worksheet. Please help me how can I consolidate or create a master sheet to extract the data from all 4 of them when ever they updates.

I tried `COUNTIFS` formula but somewhere I am not getting it.

Comment: Please share what you've exactly tried and what was the issue with it. It's always good to share your trials as you know your data the best, so you can save a lot of guessing for us.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with data being separated by 4 sheets.  Referencing a different sheet just adds one more parameter to the cell reference. You've done a good job explaining the data, but you haven't told a a thing about how you are trying to summarize (in other words, what does the mastersheet look like?)